# Specific keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using a Dutch laptop and we tend to use the English (US with dead keys).
I installed English (US), English (US, alternative international) and English (US, with euro on 5) but none of those seem to do the trick.
The first one does the accents on letters right (é, á etc) but if I want to type:

> isn´t
>   I need to press the accent key twice because it doesn´t work otherwise.
>   The second keyboard does this correctly by immediately typing the ' and there is no need to press the t before the accent appears and the same goes for the third one (only the euro sign doesn't work on the third one).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this or if I need a different keyboard setting altogether?

EDIT:
This is a picture of my keyboard. [keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbbXC.jpg)

Comment: If you want `English (US, international with dead keys)`, why don't you enable `English (US, international with dead keys)`?

Comment: I did. The problem is that it doesn´t work as it is supposed to. When typing words like doesn´t and don´t the accent only shows up if I press the button twice.

Comment: That's the expected behavior and the meaning of the term "dead keys". I can't tell if there is a layout which fits your taste exactly. If you want you can pick a layout and modify certain symbols to your liking.

Comment: Another option is to use the basic _English (US)_ layout and use a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose) for typing accented letters.

Comment: This works somewhat. I do need to press Alt Gr now when typing accents but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Picture-by-picture guide: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqPD4.jpg
Also, don't you want a Dutch keyboard layout as well? If you can, upload a photo of your physical keyboard in case this is the wrong layout so I can help you properly.

Comment: I have this version but it shows the same problem. It works for the accents on é and á and all that but when typing a word like don´t it doesn´t show the accent unless I press the button twice.
I will edit my post with a picture of my keyboard.

Comment: That is normal. On the Japanese keyboard, when writing Hiragana, I have to press the n key twice to get the character ん. That's because the letter n can form other syllables (if you're confused about the Hiragana, look it up on Wikipedia, since it does a better job of explaining it that me). It's the same with the degree symbol as well (at least, that's what I gather from your comments and post), afte pressing alt gr and 5, I have to either press 5 again or I have to press space for it to show up, otherwise it disappears. That's just how it works, there is no changing it.

Comment: Also, why do you need dead keys? You have the same keyboard as me (mine's an HP laptop too), except for the Bosnian layout printed on the keys, the trackpoint in the middle of the keyboard and the extra ctrl key to the left of the left arrow key. I would have the exact same layout in the system if I added the English (United States) layout and switched to it, but that's unnecessary, since the Bosnian keyboard has w, q, y and x as well. P.S. I added another comment since this couldn't fit in the previous one (and this close to the limit as well, only 24 characters left).

Comment: Because if I use it with standard US keyboard. I can't type é, á and all that. The thing with Japanese I am familiar with ;). The thing is that it works the way I want in Windows but I can seem to get it working in ubuntu.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to help you then, since I have the same experience in both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Oh, I just realized something. You might be talking about a keyboard layout that already has the accented letters present as dedicated keys. However, the keys are moved about the keyboard, so it's hard to type with a keyboard layout like that, since it's drastically different from your/my printed keyboard layout (the one on the physical keys). Trust me, I know (I like messing around with keyboard layouts when I have time to kill).

Answer (score 1):

English (US, international with dead keys) by design requires you to type a dead key twice (or type it followed by space) in order to type the character itself. If you type a dead key once, the system waits for the next press. Either it is a letter that can be combined with an accent, and then an accented character is produced, or it is the character itself or a space, and then the character itself is produced. If it is a letter without accented variants, nothing will appear.

If there are occasions where you want to type the accented characters immediately, e.g. during coding, then switch to a default US keyboard. With a hotkey, (Super+space under Gnome), you can quickly switch back and forth between keyboard layouts that you have set up.